# How to fix error A problem occured: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined when using the UPDATE function in php

Tags: php

I keep getting the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" when using the UPDATE function in my php, even when my blindValues match the statement variables - I can't see where the error is in my syntax. Any help would be much appreciated as am new to php and this is part of an assessment. Thank you!

```
if (isset($_POST["Update"])) {
    updateTEAM($_POST["ID"]);
}
function updateTEAM($id) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0908659_OFA", $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE TEAM SET ID=:id, TeamName=:teamname, Logo=:logo WHERE ID=". $id);

        $statement->bindValue(":id", $_POST["ID"]);
        $statement->bindValue(":teamname", $_POST["TeamName"]);
        $statement->bindValue(":logo", $_POST["Logo"]);

        $result = $statement->execute();
        if ($result) {
            $GLOBALS['message'] = "Team record was updated";
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['message'] = "The Team record was not updated";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "A problem occured: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce the error, but I reproduced your file and database and created a supposed POST. I updated with success !.

I believe this is some incorrect information coming from your POST

My file .php

```
    <?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_POST["ID"] = "123";
$_POST["TeamName"] = "Palmeiras";
$_POST["Logo"] = "palmeiras.jpg";

updateTEAM('12');




function updateTEAM($id) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e0908659_OFA", 'root', '');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE TEAM SET ID=:id, TeamName=:teamname, Logo=:logo WHERE ID=". $id);

        $statement->bindValue(":id", $_POST["ID"]);
        $statement->bindValue(":teamname", $_POST["TeamName"]);
        $statement->bindValue(":logo", $_POST["Logo"]);

        $result = $statement->execute();
        if ($result) {
            echo "Team record was updated";
        } else {
            echo "The Team record was not updated";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "A problem occured: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;

}
```

And my sql

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
    `ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TeamName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Logo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

INSERT INTO `team` (`ID`, `TeamName`, `Logo`) VALUES (12, 'Corinthians', 'corinthians.jpg');